# Set path to look up files recursively

Tags: vim

I've created a simple structure to try this feature in vim. It looks like this:

```
|__dirtest
  |____subdirtest
  | |____hello.txt
  | |____subsubdir
```

Where "dirtest" is the working directory.

I've set vim's path variable to

```
:set path+=**
```

so commands like :find can look up recursively through the subdirectories.

Everything looks fine. The output I get when I run

```
:set path?
```

gives me this:

```
path=.,/usr/include,,**
```

Though when I want to

```
:find hello.txt
```

I get:

```
E345: Can't find file "hello.txt" in path
```

Some other things that can help spot the problem:

```
:checkpath
All included files were found
```

and

```
:checkpath!
No included files
```

I disabled my .vimrc file so to make sure no other configuration was getting in the way.

Edit: It seems that the problem is in my .vimrc, since running

```
vim -Nu NONE
```

as @romainl did, and following the process I described it works as expected.

My .vimrc: https://github.com/aalencar/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc

Comment: related ... https://twitter.com/tpope/status/612991667751264256

Comment: Is your working directory actually your working directory? What does `:pwd` say? Your example works perfectly here with `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: @romainl :pwd shows /Users/aalencar/dirtest

Comment: @xandercoded looks like not a good option, but I like to explore this kind of features just for fun and also learn a bit, if possible :)

Comment: I am running on the default vim that comes with OS X, if it helps.

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/a/LFbPy) is the expected behavior with the default Vim on Mac OS X.

Comment: @romainl Did the same thing you did in your gif and it worked, then I tried to do the same process with my .vimrc on and I am still getting the error. I edited the post with my .vimrc on github. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Also when I run `:set path=.,/usr/include/,**` it works as a charm, though if I run `:set path=.,/usr/include/,,**` to set replicate the configuration when I do just `:set path+=**` it doesn't work.